# Laravel 5.3 Many to many relationships pivot table insert data

Tags: many-to-many, pivot-table, laravel-5.3, multi-select, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am working on a laravel 5.3 application where I have to working with a form like below:-

[image]

After completing the Personal info tab's fields user will go to 'medical & Dental History Tab' :-
[image]

After select patient previous dental histories from multiple select combo box if submit button pressed the patient info  along with previous dental histories shall saved in database table.

I am approaching this scenario making following three  table:
1. tbl_patient
2. tbl_dental_history
3. tbl_patient_dental_history

[image]

here tbl_patient and tbl_dental_history have a many to many relationship. My question is how could I save both personal info and Medical & Dental history tabs field at a time. Note that I now how to save many to many relationship tables data as following:-

```
$patient=Patient::findById(id);
//Dental history multi select data
$dhistories=$request->dhistory;
foreach ($dhistories as $dhistory) {
      $patient->dentalhistories()->save($dhistory);
    }
```

Patient.php Model:-

```
protected $table='patients';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
protected $fillable=['first_name','middle_name','last_name','dob', 'first_name',
                    'middle_name', 'last_name', 'dob', 'gender','status', 'address', 'city',
                     'post_code', 'phone', 'email', 'refered_by'];

public function dentalhistories(){
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Modules\PATIENT\Models\DentalHistory','patient_dental_history',
    'patient_id','dhistory_id');
}
```

DentalHistory.php Model:-

```
protected $table='dental_history';
 protected $primaryKey = 'id';
 protected $fillable=['dhistory'];
```

Am I doing right? Expecting suggestions from experts.. how could I save all data for this scenario? Thanks advance